# Updating Data having same id but different Data in Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a record with same ID but different data in both rows
While updating the final result should be the last record of that ID present in data.
Example

```
ID | Name | PermanentAddrss | CurrentLocation
1  |  R1  | INDIA           |    USA
1  |  R1  | INDIA           |    UK
```

Now for `ID` 1 the record which will be loaded in database

```
1|R1|INDIA|UK
```

How this can be done in SQL server for multiple records?

Comment: Is there any other column with an identity or datetime column to sort? With the current data which you have given, it will be tough to identify the last record

Comment: you can try Row_Number() to update the first record in each group of id.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the latest `ID` value by:

```
SELECT B.ID, A.NAME, A.PERMANENTADDRS, A.CURRENTLOCATION
FROM
(SELECT ID, NAME, PERMANENTADDRS, CURRENTLOCATION, MAX(RNUM) AS LATEST_ID FROM
    (SELECT ID, NAME, PERMANENTADDRS, CURRENTLOCATION, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS RNUM FROM YOUR_TABLE)
GROUP BY ID, NAME, PERMANENTADDRS, CURRENTLOCATION) A
INNER JOIN
YOUR_TABLE B
ON A.LATEST_ID = B.ID;
```

This will take the last populated record for a given `ID` value. If the logic for latest record is different, it can be appropriately incorporated in the query.

Comment: the logic correct.I tried this but the data is getting misplaced by rows.I need to ask my client for Last_updated_time or anything like which will help me to identify the latest record. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that SQL server does not store or fetch data in order of data insertion, so to find the latest/last record you should have some way to order the records.
This is typically a timestamp column like `last_modified_date`. Your current table is prime candidate for a slow changing dimension type 2; and you should consider implementing it.
See **[explanation](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/type-2/)** on Kimball's group site.

If you are really not affected by any order and just need a row for each id you can try below query.

```
select 
ID, 
Name,
PermanentAddress,
CurrentLocation
from
(select
*,
row_number() over(partition by id order by (select null)) r
from yourtable)t
where r=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!!